# How to detect if a file has a UTF-8 BOM in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to write a script that will automatically remove UTF-8 BOMs from a file. I'm having trouble detecting whether the file has one in the first place or not. Here is my code:

```
function has-bom {
    # Test if the file starts with 0xEF, 0xBB, and 0xBF
    head -c 3 "$1" | grep -P '\xef\xbb\xbf'
    return $?
}
```

For some reason, `head` seems to be ignoring the BOM in front of the file. As an example, running this

```
printf '\xef\xbb\xbf' > file
head -c 3 file
```

won't print anything.

I tried looking for an option in `head --help` that would let me work around this, but no luck. Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First, let's demonstrate that `head` is actually working correctly:

```
$ printf '\xef\xbb\xbf' >file
$ head -c 3 file 
$ head -c 3 file | hexdump -C
00000000  ef bb bf                                          |...|
00000003
```

Now, let's create a working function `has_bom`.  If your `grep` supports `-P`, then one option is:

```
$ has_bom() { head -c3 "$1" | LC_ALL=C grep -qP '\xef\xbb\xbf'; }
$ has_bom file && echo yes
yes
```

Currently, only GNU `grep` supports `-P`.

Another option is to use bash's `$'...'`:

```
$ has_bom() { head -c3 "$1" | grep -q $'\xef\xbb\xbf'; }
$ has_bom file && echo yes
yes
```

`ksh` and `zsh` also support `$'...'` but this construct is not POSIX and `dash` does not support it.

Notes:

1. The use of an explicit `return $?` is optional.  The function will, by default, return with the exit code of the last command run.
2. I have used the POSIX form for defining functions.  This is equivalent to the bash form but gives you one less problem to deal with if you ever have to run the function under another shell.
3. bash does accept the use of the character `-` in a function name but this is a controversial feature.  I replaced it with `_` which is more widely accepted.  (For more on this issue, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168222/53604).)
4. The `-q` option to `grep` makes it quiet, meaning that it still sets a proper exit code but it does not send any characters to stdout.

Comment: Huh, never knew Bash supported hex string literals. Anyways, thanks for the great answer!

Comment: hi, may i ask in line `head -c 3 file | hexdump -c `, what does the `-c` do? The previous one seems to 1) limit number of characters output 2) restrict line number (maybe) to 0000000 and 0000003; but the latter makes the output, which is supposed to be "be bf" etc., into replacement marker. I am using bash and testing on a text file generated under Windows, original encoding=GB18030. Thanks.

Comment: @CrazyFrog `head -c 3 file` writes the first three characters of `file` to standard out.  `hexdump -C` formats those those characters in a human-friendly way as hexadecimal.

Comment: @John1024 thank you I found the manual! It’s weird though I generate BOM specific with code at the beginning of my text file but this command does not see it.

Comment: @CrazyFrog Without seeing the code, I can't tell why it is not generating a BOM for you.  You might want to open a question showing the code in detail and documenting the seemingly missing BOM issue.

Comment: @John1024 That is probably what I should do. I will review the code myself again. There has to be a mistake on my part. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I applied the followings for the first read line:

```
read c
if (( "$(printf "%d" "'${c:0:1}")" == 65279 ))  ; then c="${c:1}" ; fi
```

This simply removes the BOM from the variable.

Answer (score 0):

In pure bash, a solution could be:

```
function has_bom() {
    local bom
    LANG=C read -r -N 3 bom < "$1"
    [[ "$bom" == $'\xef\xbb\xbf' ]]
}
```

Test with a file with BOM:

```
$ F=test.with-bom
$ head -c 5 $F | hd
00000000  ef bb bf c3 a9                                    |.....|
$ has_bom "$F" && echo "$F has a BOM" || echo "$F has no BOM"
test.with-bom has a BOM
```

Test when no BOM:

```
$ F=test.utf8
$ head -c 5 "$F" | hd
00000000  c3 a9 6c c3 a9                                    |..l..|
$ has_bom "$F" && echo "$F has a BOM" || echo "$F has no BOM"
test.utf8 has no BOM
```

Answer (score 0):

Script below helped me do the job.

```
FILE_INPUT="$1"

has_bom() { head -c3 "$1" | grep -q $'\xef\xbb\xbf'; }

if has_bom $FILE_INPUT; then
  echo "File has a BOM"
else
  echo "File does not have a BOM"
fi
```

There's just one gotcha. BOM is usually at the top of the file. If your file was preprocessed e.g. sorted then the BOM will be misplaced and the script above will not work.