# Python keeps adding character 65279 to the beginning of my file

Tags: python

I use [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977843/how-to-detect-if-a-file-has-a-utf-8-bom-in-bash) `head -c 1 /path_to_file/file` and see that the file starts with an alphabetical character. In this case it's letter `n`.

But when I want to read its first character in python, I get character 65279 (zero-width or  BOM):

```
first=open('/path_to_file/file').read(1)
print (first, ord(first))
```

This prints:

> 65279

Why is it so? It seems that python keeps adding that BOM to the beginning of my file, or bash does not read that BOM character at all.

When I open the file in [VS Code](https://pinter.org/archives/9915), I see `UTF-8` at the bottom, not `UTF-8 with BOM`.

It seems that Python adds that BOM to the beginning of my file.

Is there a settings for Python to configure this? How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: It there any actual problem the BOM causes?

Comment: Are you sure you opened the same file? I've never heard of a case where python would add a BOM to a file on reading.

Comment: @KlausD., we're using a third party linter and not having BOM is one of its lint rules. We constantly see huge dirty list of lint rules related to BOM.

Comment: @Sören, yeah I'm sure. If you're interested, I can show you the code via a remote session.

Comment: What OS are you on? What filesystem?

Comment: @nog642, Ubuntu 22.04, how can I know about my file system?

Comment: @Bigboy You can type the command `lsblk -f` to see all the mounted filesystems with their type and mountpoint. Whichever mountpoint your file is contained in (for example if the file is `/a/b/c` and theres one mountpoint at `/` and another at `/a`, then you want the one at `/a` since it's closer) is the filesystem. It's probably ext4 if it's on your main hard drive. Anyway, how was the file created?

Comment: @nog642 I couldn't figure out the response of `lsblk -f` command. I created the file using VS Code.

Comment: @Bigboy Try running the python code on some other files created in other ways. Does every file you try start with a BOM?

Comment: @nog642, I tested it. This problem happens only on C# files created using VS Code.

Comment: @Bigboy Are you running python from the terminal or an IDE? Can you check the contents of the file some other way besides python, head, and VS Code?

Comment: I'm using Python from the terminal to statically check codes. What other option do I have for this?