# PHP / Output file Encoding / Changing from ANSI to UTF-8-BOM

Tags: php, file, encoding, utf-8, byte-order-mark

Is there a way to prevent PHP to auto-changing encoding for Excel-file or set encoding?

Already tried:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'ANSI');
ini_set('output_encoding', 'ANSI');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=ANSI');
```

Using "phpoffice/phpexcel". If I save built Excel-file on server, and download saved file without PHP, than encoding for that file in NotePad++ is ANSI, and file opens correctly in MS Excel program.

But if I tried to return that correct file by PHP:

```
readfile($file_path);
// OR directly write to output
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Then downloaded Excel-file encoding will be UTF-8-BOM, end MS Excel shows for that file only strange symbols. But I can open that file in NotePad++ and change encoding to ANSI, then that file correctly opens in MS Excel.

How to return with PHP that Excel-file to client without auto-changing encoding of that file?

Comment: Are you sure your PHP script itself was not saved _with_ a BOM?

Comment: @CBroe, you asking about PHP-scrip that reads and returns Excel-file? That one just UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Sure it is UTF-8 _without_ a BOM? Because if it has one, that will likely be the first "output" your script sends to the client.

Comment: @CBroe, that is without ["yes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977843/how-to-detect-if-a-file-has-a-utf-8-bom-in-bash):  
```shell
head -c3 "show_xls.php" | grep -q $'\xef\xbb\xbf' && echo yes
```
  
And locally NotePad++ show only "UTF-8"

Comment: And you are calling that script _directly_, it does not get included into something else? If you are able to call `$objWriter->save` in there, then it must embed other files though, I suppose - maybe a BOM coming from one of those?

Comment: @CBroe, need to check all included_files (147)? If any has BOM, then all outputted to client will be with BOM?

Comment: I'd start by checking what _just_ `readfile($file_path);` without _any_ additionally included scripts results in. And maybe clearing the output buffer helps, if there is already "a BOM" caught in there at this point. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49626066/1427878

Comment: @CBroe, yep, just `readfile($excel_file_path)` outputs correct Excel-file with ANSI.
  OK, thanks, will try to find that intruder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77081854/php-output-file-encoding-changing-from-ansi-to-utf-8-bom#comment135887584_77081854) and [Detecting UTF BOM (byte order mark) using PHP](https://anupamsaha.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/detecting-utf-byte-order-mark-using-php/), before set "attachment" headers putted that:

```php
$has_bomed_files = false;
foreach (get_included_files() as $file_path)
{
    $str = file_get_contents($file_path);
    $bom = pack("CCC", 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf);
    if (0 === strncmp($str, $bom, 3))
    {
        $has_bomed_files = true;
        print $file_path;
        print '<br>';
    }
}

if ($has_bomed_files)
    exit(__FILE__ . ":" . __LINE__);
```

And found, was BOM in one Class, I`ve removed that BOM, and now PHP returns correct Excel-file.